# My Acer V206HQL's display is half cut off from the top & same is reflecting in the bottom

Tags: windows-10, display, hardware-failure, external-display, acer

My Acer display is half cut off from the top, the same is visible at the bottom of the display divided by a white line, also there is a fringing issue, I can guarantee you this is hardware related not software related.

Upper part of the display try to notice the mouse:
[image: Upper part of the display try to notice the mouse]

Bottom part of the display the same mouse is showing in the bottom:
[image: Bottom part of the display the same mouse is showing in the bottom]

The fringing I was talking about:
[image: The fringing I was talking about]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Seems like your mouse is wrapping, meaning can move directly from top-most to bottom-most. Check if this is the case by moving the mouse upward "beyond" the screen-top.

Comment: No, it's not about that it is just the screen cutting part of the bottom & reflecting it down bellow it's actually the reflection that is casing this.